# Handle user's cancel in custom Keycloak SPI Authenticator

Tags: java, authentication, jboss, keycloak

I need to handle user's cancel in custom Keycloak SPI Authenticator.
I implemented it and it works fine. All I need is to cancel login flow and start from the begging when user hit cancel

```
    @Override
    public void action(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {
        logger.debug("action called ... context = " + context);
        String cancel = context.getHttpRequest().getDecodedFormParameters().getFirst("cancel");
        if (cancel != null) {
            context.cancelLogin();
            context.resetFlow();
            return;
        }
// OK handling...
}
```

In my case I'm getting login page but with wrong URL:

http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/realm1/login-actions/authenticate?execution=bb1fb7c3-0b59-4a07-b997-b619c6f9ea2a&client_id=realm1-client&tab_id=YJxYk7osJaU

instead of URL like this when I enter secured page first time:

http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/realm1/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=realm1-client&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8081%2Fsso%2Flogin&state=2cc038b9-2c69-4648-ac39-e5864bc05ee9&login=true&scope=openid

Answer (score 0):

Ah all I need is to left only row (or put it the last before return):

```
context.cancelLogin();
```

On my custom application I need to handle endpoint with parameters where KK will redirect me

```
/sso/login?error=access_denied&state=923e5b18-1d8e-4c96-9fed-c1dd122065bb
```

Comment: I am trying to achieve a similar functionality where my custom authentication SPI will perform a `context.cancelLogin()` and which will redirect the user back to the calling application, my question is how should the calling application infer the response and understand that the user now needs to be redirected to the initial login page which started the authentication flow.

Comment: Just in case, according to the documentation, context.cancelLogin() should only be executed in browser-based flows.